# Popup to Capture Image or Upload Image from Gallery and making the Image as the ImageButton Background

Tags: android, datepicker, android-camera

After Clicking the Imagebutton it will prompt you to select an option either capture image or upload from gallery and once you complete the capturing process you will get the image as the background image for the image button. And it also has the select custom date design feature. Hope this Code will help Everyone I suffered a lot doing these small things So this I'm doing as a social service.

```
public class Add_Song extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    Button btnSelectDate;
    Button scanBtn;
    ImageButton a;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;


        // variables to save user selected date and time
    public  int year,month,day;  
// declare  the variables to Show/Set the date and time when Time and  Date Picker Dialog first appears
    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay;
    public Add_Song()
    {
                // Assign current Date and Time Values to Variables
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_song);
        a = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                selectImage();

            }

        });
        btnSelectDate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectDate);
        scanBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnscan);
           // Set ClickListener on btnSelectDate
           // Set ClickListener on btnSelectDate
        scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSelectDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Show the DatePickerDialog
                 showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

}

    private File savebitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
          String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
          OutputStream outStream = null;
         // String temp = null;
            File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "temp.png");
          if (file.exists()) {
           file.delete();
           file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "temp.png");

          }

          try {
           outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
           bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
           outStream.flush();
           outStream.close();

          } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null;
          }
          return file;
         }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.movie_library, menu);
            return true;
        }
         private void selectImage() {



                final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };



                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Add_Song.this);

                builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");

                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                        if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))

                        {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                            File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");

                            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                            //pic = f;

                            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


                        }

                        else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))

                        {

                            Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);



                        }

                        else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {

                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }

                    }

                });

                builder.show();

            }
    // Register  DatePickerDialog listener
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
                           new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                       // the callback received when the user "sets" the Date in the DatePickerDialog
                               public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yearSelected,
                                                     int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                  year = yearSelected;
                                  month = monthOfYear;
                                  day = dayOfMonth;
                                  // Set the Selected Date in Select date Button
                                  btnSelectDate.setText("Date selected : "+day+"-"+month+"-"+year);
                               }
                           };
                           @Override
                           protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
                               switch (id) {
                               case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                        // create a new DatePickerDialog with values you want to show
                                   return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                                               mDateSetListener,
                                               mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                               }
                               return null;
                           }

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if(v.getId()==R.id.btnscan){
                                Intent cmer = new Intent(this, CameraTestActivity.class);
                                startActivityForResult(cmer, 3);
                            }
                        }
                        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

                              if (requestCode == 3) {

                                 if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
                                     String result=data.getStringExtra("result");   
                                     scanBtn.setText(result);
                                 }
                                 if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
                                     //Write your code if there's no result
                                 }
                              }else if (requestCode == 1){
                                  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                                            //h=0;
                                            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());

                                            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {

                                                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {

                                                    f = temp;
                                                    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                                                   //pic = photo;
                                                    break;

                                                }

                                            }

                                            try {

                                                Bitmap bitmap;

                                                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();



                                                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),

                                                        bitmapOptions); 



                                                a.setImageBitmap(bitmap);




                                                String path = android.os.Environment

                                                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()

                                                        + File.separator

                                                        + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                                                //p = path;

                                                f.delete();

                                                OutputStream outFile = null;

                                                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

                                                try {

                                                    outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);

                                                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                            //pic=file;
                                                    outFile.flush();

                                                    outFile.close();


                                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                                } catch (IOException e) {

                                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                                }

                                            } catch (Exception e) {

                                                e.printStackTrace();

                                            }
                              }
                            }else if (requestCode == 2){
                                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                                     Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                                       // h=1;
                        //imgui = selectedImage;
                                        String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                                        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);

                                        c.moveToFirst();

                                        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);

                                        String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);

                                        c.close();

                                        Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));


                                        Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath+"");


                                        a.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                                }
                            }                        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Rasha, however I seem to be having a few problems in deciphering where the result codes are set? For example RESULT_OK?

EDIT

Nevermind, for anyone else that runs into this, the result codes are children of Activity, so just change to Activity.RESULT_OK etc

Comment: I can understand what your problem was, but u should understand that u can use either result code or result OK it doesn't matter actually. It all depends on your coding i have tried both ways and they seem to work perfectly. For example if you use Result code under result OK then u wont have to repeat result ok, but according to my logic i had to do it that way :) Hope i answered your question. Any other problems please feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
public void chooseImageDialog(final String title, String message,
            final Context context, final boolean redirectToPreviousScreen) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Gallery",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Camera",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intentfile = new Intent(
                        "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                startActivityForResult(intentfile, 2);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

call where you want open it..like that

```
chooseImageDialog("", "Choose profile pic ?", this, false);


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri chosenImageUri = data.getData();
                String imagepath = getpath(chosenImageUri);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            _ivSelectProfilePic.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                    bitmap,100,100,false));////here set your image

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Unable to get Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                _ivSelectProfilePic.setImageBitmap(Bitmap
                        .createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 120, 120, false));//here set your image
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activityname.this, "Unable to get Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

///this is use get the path of image //////

```
private String getpath(Uri chosenImageUri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(chosenImageUri, projection, null, null,
            null);
    int column = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer sister, but My one is already working, This code is just for trying to help others. Anyway thanks :)